# Matlab figure contents lost while saving as eps/pdf

Tags: matlab, pdf, eps

I have tried most of the usually used options (print(figr, '-depsc', 'cross_corr.eps');) to save a matlab figure as eps/pdf but each time I do it, the figure contents are saved partially and perhaps one quarter of it is lost.
I have shared the figure here: http://ge.tt/2ZrsdD02/v/0?c

Using the options such as the following save it completely but I prefer it save it directly inti eps/pdf:

```
print(figr, '-dpng', 'cross_corr.png');
```

Comment: Exactly what gets lost? I'm unable to replicate. Anyway,  a couple of things you could try: `set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')` prior to printing.  On the matlab file exchange, there's a function called `export_fig` that I've had good luck with in terms of preserving figure contents, you may find it useful as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help much.please see my 'answer' to know what exactly is lost.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you have very small values in the `'PaperPosition'` property of the figure. Try changing them to the default ones,

```
set(figr, 'PaperPosition', [0.634517 6.34517 20.3046 15.2284])
```

and then apply your `print(figr, '-depsc', 'cross_corr.eps')`.

I attach results on my computer without and with `'PaperPosition'` correction (using GSview with bounding box showed):

[image]

[image]

Also, consider reducing font size to avoid overlapped text:

```
set(findobj('type','text'), 'Fontsize', 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the quality doesn't seem to be ok. Please see my answer below.

Comment: The quality is very good because it's a vector file (eps). Don't be mislead by the above figures; they are just screen captures

Answer (score 0):

If I first enlarge the figure size (by using the middle button on the top right), and then save it as eps, I get this: http://ge.tt/1Pv8YE02/v/0

The quality is very nice as compared to all other options and the content are also ok.

Its not possible to automate it through script?...

Comment: Make your figure large from the beginning: `scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
fig_handle = figure('Position',[0 0 scrsz(3), scrsz(4)]);`